# rails 3 including fields from joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, join, attributes

I have the folowing structure:

Database:

```
create_table :recipes do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :categoryname
end

create_table :ingredients do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :categoryname
  t.string :defaultunit
  t.integer :price
end

create_table :recipeingredients do |t|
  t.integer :recipe_id
  t.integer :ingredient_id
  t.integer :quantity
  t.string :unit
end
```

Models:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :recipeingredients
   has_many :recipes, :through=>:recipeingredients
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipeingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipeingredients
end

class Recipeingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

`irb(main):337:0* r=Recipe.find(1)
  Recipe Load (0.5ms) SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Recipe id: 1, name: "Tiramisu", categoryname: "édesség", created_at: "2013-02-26 09:31:55", updated_at: "2013-02-26 09:
31:55">`

`irb(main):338:0> r.ingredients
  Ingredient Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipeingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipeingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipeingredients"."recipe_id" = 1
=> [#<Ingredient id: 1, name: "mascarpone", categoryname: "tejtermék", defaultunit: "gr", price: 500, created_at: "2013-02-26 09:32:21", updated_at: "2013-02-26 09:32:21">]`

What I would like achive is to be able to reach recipeingredients.quantity and recipeingredients.unit in r.ingredients.

I believe it could be achieved by changing the query somehow so that it returns something like `SELECT * FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN...`

My goal is to be able to list the quantities as well as the properties of ingredients using one for cycle in the view.

Is there a way to do it? So far did not work anything what I found on forums.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you want it sporadically or all the time, that is, always load the ingredients everytime you load a recipe. If that is your case, then you should define it in the association:

```
has_many :ingredients, :include => true ...
```

If you want to specifically load the ingredients on some cases, then you need to do as specified in the previous answer (which was downvoted, but I don't know why.):

```
Recipe.includes(:recipeingredients).first(5)
```

check the SQL query output to visualize the benefits.

Comment: Recipe.includes(:recipeingredients).first(5) this one works. Thank you. Could you help with the other version? I put the code in to the recipe model like this: has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipeingredients, :include=>true  this actually seem nothing to do. do you ment this way?

Comment: What do you mean, it does not work? What's the output? What should have worked that didn't? about the :include option: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score -1):

This will fetch a Recipe and all connected Ingredients and RecipeIngredients in one go:

```
r = Recipe.includes(:ingredients, :recipeingredients).find(1)
```

After that you can loop like this (HAML view):

```
- r.recipeingredients.each do |ri|
  Ingredient:
  = ri.ingredient.name
  quantity:
  = ri.quantity
```